# system() has been disabled error message

Tags: php, wordpress

I have copied a wordpress website over to the correct domain but I get the following error message when I go to view it:

```
Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/paddocch/public_html/wildlionmedia.co.uk/wp-includes/cron.php on line 262
```

http://www.wildlionmedia.co.uk/

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `system()` function is used to allow PHP to execute commands on the system's command line shell. Your new hosting service has disabled that feature because it can be a vulnerability.

You'll want to check out your `php.ini` file and search for an entry titled - `disable_functions`. In there there are a list of functions that have been disabled. You can remove what you want from the list (including the `system()` function.

If you do not have access to your `php.ini` file, you'll have to talk to your hosting provider and ask them to enable that feature (or disable to limitation).

For more info - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions