# PHP Warning: exec() unable to fork

Tags: php, centos

So here is a little background info on my setup. Running Centos with apache and php 5.2.17.  I have a website that lists products from many different retailers websites.  I have crawler scripts that run to grab products from each website.  Since every website is different, each crawler script had to be customized to crawl the particular retailers website.  So basically I have 1 crawler per retailer.  At this time I have 21 crawlers that are constantly running to gather and refresh the products from these websites.  Each crawler is a php file and once the php script is done running it checks to ensure its the only instance of itself running and at the very end of the script it uses exec to start itself all over again while the original instance closes.  This helps protect against memory leaks since each crawler restarts itself before it closes. However recently I will check the crawler scripts and notice that one of them Isnt running anymore and in the error log I find the following.

```
PHP Warning:  exec() [<a href='function.exec'>function.exec</a>]: Unable to fork [nice -n 20 php -q /home/blahblah/crawler_script.php &gt;/dev/null &amp;]
```

This is what is supposed to start this particular crawler over again however since it was "unable to fork" it never restarted and the original instance of the crawler ended like it normally does.

Obviously its not a permission issue because each of these 21 crawler scripts runs this exec command every 5 or 10 minutes at the end of its run and most of the time it works as it should.  This seems to happen maybe once or twice a day.  It seems as though its a limit of some sort as I have only just recently started to see this happen ever since I added my 21st crawler.  And its not always the same crawler that gets this error it will be any one of them at a random time that are unable to fork its restart exec command.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing php to be unable to fork or maybe even a better way to handle these processes as to get around the error all together?  Is there a process limit I should look into or something of that nature?  Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Process limit

> *"Is there a process limit I should look into"*

It's suspected somebody (system admin?) set limitation of `max user process`. Could you try this?

```
$ ulimit -a
....
....
max user processes              (-u) 16384
....
```

Run preceding command in PHP. Something like :

```
echo system("ulimit -a");
```

I searched whether php.ini or httpd.conf has this limit, but I couldn't find it.

### Error Handling

> *"even a better way to handle these processes as to get around the error all together?*"

The third parameter of `exec()` returns exit code of `$cmd`. 0 for success, non zero for error code. Refer to http://php.net/function.exec .

```
exec($cmd, &$output, &$ret_val);

if ($ret_val != 0)
{
    // do stuff here
}
else
{
    echo "success\n";
}
```

Comment: ulimit -a when ran in php returns max user processes (-u) 257294 when ran from ssh (root) i get 14335.  I like the script at the end to test whether or not the shell command failed, i could use that in a loop to retry until it passes i suppose.

Comment: @DaneLandanHarvey Hello Dane. yes, I think you need to keep track of return code of `exec()` and determine what you should do according to error code. Thanks.

Comment: I have now implemented the return code of the exec into a while loop so it will now sleep for 2 seconds and retry until successful.  This will work, but Ide still like to know what was causing the problem in the first place.  Thanks for your help InoS Heo!

Comment: This is what I get: Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: @Binod You can't turn on system() if you don't have permission to modify php.ini. please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121185/system-has-been-disabled-error-message

Answer (score 7):

In my case (large PHPUnit test suite) it would say `unable to fork` once the process hit 57% memory usage.  So, one more thing to watch for, it may not be a process limit but rather memory.

Comment: Why 57% and not 100%? What's special about 57%?

Comment: If all the other processes use kinda constant % of memory, Derek's PHP memory limit `n` could be equal to 57% of total memory used (combined with those other processes). That's probably why he mentioned it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is often caused by the system or the process or running out of available memory. Be sure that you have enough by running `free -m`. You will get a result like the following:

`total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       7722        262         19        189        803
-/+ buffers/cache:       6729       1255
Swap:            0          0          0`

The buffers/cache line is what you want to look at. Notice free memory is 1255 MB on this machine. When running your program keep trying `free -m` and check `free` memory to see if this falls into the low hundreds. If it does you will need to find a way to run you program while consumer less memory.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same problem and I tried this and it worked for me;

```
ulimit -n 4096
```

Comment: Just clarification to whoever reads the answer. This command changes the `open files` limit to 4096

Comment: @Nikita웃 Important, because of `-n` ... but with `-u` we are talking about `max user processes`

Comment: Why 4096? Anything special there?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this issue, it could be several problems as outlined in this question's answer.

However, my problem was my nginx user did not have a proper shell to execute the commands I wanted. Adding .bashrc to the nginx user's home directory fixed this.