# PhantomJS on server - PHP exec unable to fork

Tags: javascript, php, windows, phantomjs

**Problem:** Getting `Warning: exec(): Unable to fork` with `hello.js`

**Question:** How can I make it work?

**Description:**
I'm trying to make phantomJs work on a Windows server. I have the following files on the `public_html` folder:

1. phantomjs.exe
2. index.php
3. hello.js

Where `index.php` is simply:

```
<?php $response = exec('phantomjs.exe hello.js');
```

And `hello.js` is:

```
console.log("Hello world!");
phantom.exit();
```

When I run `index.php` I get the following error:

```
Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [phantomjs.exe hello.js] in D:\sites\creditflow.com\public_html\index.php on line 1
```

The code above is currently hosted [here](http://79.170.44.202/creditflow.com/index.php).

**Question:** how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be permissions on phantomjs.exe, have you tried changing them? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php#32601 Could be helpful

Also, have you tried using a full path?

Must say however, an exe in public_html sounds risky to me.. I *think* (with the wrong permission config) that anybody could execute that remotely, and possibly pass a path to any file on your server, including non public files.

Cannot think of any reason it would need to specifically go there rather than in a safer non web accessible location.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a lot of control over the server at the moment, so permissions could be an issue. However, I could change the permissions on all files to 766, but I still got the same error. Right now I'm trying to create a WAMP on EC2 to further investigate on that. I also tried using full paths in many different ways, but the problem still occurred. On the security issue, I'm new to this thing so I really don't know how to deal with it, do you know any good resource to read about websecurity?

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is probably related to memory, not permissions. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork) a question regarding the same issue.

It could be a leak somewhere else in your code, however [phantomjs itself has some issues with memory consuming](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/198).