# PHP Warning: exec(): Unable to fork

Tags: php, linux

> PHP Warning:  exec(): Unable to fork [rm some_file.txt] in some.php on
>   line 111

There is a question that has been asked before about this subject [PHP Warning: exec() unable to fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork) I have similar problem but it not the same.

```
ulimit -a 

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0                                        
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited                                
scheduling priority             (-e) 0                                        
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited                                
pending signals                 (-i) 31364                                    
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64                                       
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited                                
open files                      (-n) 1024                                     
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8                                        
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200                                   
real-time priority              (-r) 0                                        
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240                                    
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited                                
max user processes              (-u) 31364                                    
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited                                
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

My limits are shown above and it looks like there is nothing with low limit on server that can affect this error.

I tried to unsetting variables after using them both with unset and by setting them to null to free up memory. But it has no effect.

```
unset($var);
$var = null;
```

Unable to fork error occuring because of exhausting of some resources but I can't find the reason. **Can you suggest me to which logs I should look?**

Any ideas or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Does the output from exec() give you a clue? Catch the return code and inspect it as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork. Also routing `PHP Warning` to `ErrorException` and handling them is always a good idea.

Comment: In terms of logs. Pretty sure you'll see `max user processes` or whatever violation show up in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @S.Pinkus thanks for suggestions I will try them soon

Comment: @S.Pinkus There is no /var/log/syslog on server. I tried this command tail -f $( locate syslog )

Comment: That's quite weird. /var/log/ is the standard place for logs. Exactly what's there depends on your logging config which should be in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. cat that. It's fairly easy to see what's going where.

Comment: So your running this from command line I assume. Is the process terminating immediately or do you get a bunch of these messages?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas or workaround for this problem?

The problem is likely a flaw in your code - like it was in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20649541/2038383. So the work around is fixing it.

> Can you suggest to me in which logs I should look?

There is your PHP logs, then your system / kernel logs.

You already know where to get the PHP log and what is in it by default. Unfortunately your not going to get much more out of PHP. You could catch the error yourself with [set_error_handler()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) but that won't give you any more useful info (it'll give you PHP's "errno" but not UNIX's errno).

As for system logs; I said in comments check your `syslog`. There might be something in there, and it's always a good starting point. But actually you won't generally see ulimit violations in syslog. Some will  get logged (example `stack size` generates segfault which gets logged) but many won't. This post deals with how to get logs of `ulimit` violations:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139011/how-do-i-configure-logging-for-ulimits. Surprisingly non trivial.

The way system `ulimit` violations are supposed to be reported by system call is by setting an errno. For example, if `max user processes` is hit `fork()` will return `EAGAIN`.

So ... you need to get at that UNIX `errno` to know what is really going on. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way in PHP (there is [posix_errno()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-errno.php), but pretty sure that is limited to PHP's posix_XXX function library). Also note, it's [PHP generating the "Unable to fork"](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/exec.c#L120) message. How that maps to actual system call error is not completely transparent.

So best off looking at other ways to debug of which there are plenty. Like system monitoring tools: `ps`, `dstat`, `strace` might be a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Comment: No worries, got a bit carried away looking into it :). Was fun.