# PHP exec : Unable to fork

Tags: php, exec

I am calling exec in PHP in a shared hosting environment and I am sometimes getting non null exit codes.

I sometimes receive either a -1 exit code and following warning "PHP warning: Warning: exec(): Unable to fork", either a 254 exit code with no PHP warning.

I guess I am running out of some resource (memory, max number of processes, ?) but I cannot figure out of which resource exactly.

Could you please indicate me which logs I should check so that I know what the exact problem is or which exact limit I have reached ?

I have seen a few articles about this same error but none enabled me to identify precisely my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork

Comment: Hi Andrew, unfortunately I logged ulimit -a but it didn't help