# PHP execute program whit a JSON argument

Tags: php, json, exec

I would like to execute a program with a JSON argument. I try this but that doesn't work

```
$json = file_get_contents("request.json");
$cmd = 'Program.exe "' . $json . '"';
$result = exec($cmd, $output, $return_value);
```

That gives me this error: `Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [MyCommand]`

I don't know how to send a JSON string as an argument.

I work on Windows Server 2012 R2, Wamp Server for Apache (Please don't ask me why I don't use IIS), and the commande exec in PHP work with another Exe file.
I think that my JSON is too long or this command doesn't accept some characters.

If someone has the answer that will be cool?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: exec() unable to fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork)

Comment: what does request.json return ? maybe it's not your php but your shell command that return this error

Answer (score 0):

I finish to find my issue. The Json that I send is to long, the commands exec() accepts a limited size and it's why that don't work.
To solve this, I give the file path to my program who take it and read it.