# How can I pass an image in base64 string as a parameter to a Python script?

Tags: python, php, laravel, image, base64

I am trying to pass as a parameter in a python script a string in base 64.

`$request->current_image` is my image in base64 and i have another argument $email. The PHP code is:

```
public function access(Request $request)
    {

   $output = exec("python login.py $request->current_image $email ");
   
   dd($output);
    }
```

I get this error :

> exec(): Unable to fork [python login.py data:image/png;base64,iV.....

Is there another way ?

Comment: Which language is this script in?

Comment: This isn't really a Python question as things stand; the problem is how to communicate data from PHP to a process that it's spawning with `exec`. Though making this work might require adapting the Python script. If it's not your own code, check the documentation; it's highly unlikely that the Python is expecting information to be provided this way - it should either be expecting a *file name* in the command-line arguments (in which case you could just have the PHP write a temp file first), or expecting the raw data on the standard input.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - It would work as long as the base64 didn't have embedded newlines and its length is less than `getconf ARG_MAX`. That's 2097152 on my system, but results may vary. (assuming this is linux/mac)

Comment: I suppose so, but it's not exactly the recommended approach for command-line tool design.

Comment: Is there more interesting information in that trailing ....? You could try `exec("python --version")` to see if php (its php?) can find the python executable.

Comment: Yes it's not my code , in the original code it sends the image string from a form(POST) in html to the python script which retrieve it with cgi.FieldStorage() .. but in my case i'm working with laravel i get the form values from my controller and i'm trying to pass them to the script as arguments with sys.argvs[] .. and i don't know how to do that

Comment: But you can change the code? I'm not a php person (is this php?) but an option would be to pipe it into python's stdin and let the script read it there.

Comment: @tdelaney yes its php and its works when i use normal arguments

Comment: How do i pipe it ? i'm sorry i was looking about that and can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

base64 encoded image string has special characters like `:`,`/`,`,`

So, firstly you must change python parameter to string for proper command:

```
public function access(Request $request){
   $output = exec("python login.py '$request->current_image' '$email'");   
   dd($output);
}
```

And check this answer for "unable to fork" error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20649541/3121398