# Sending PHP emails?

Tags: php, email, smtp, hosting, web-hosting

Like @user1096057 in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121185/system-has-been-disabled-error-message) I'm trying to send an email with PHP `Mail()`

and I receive the same warning

```
Warning: mail() has been disabled for security reasons in 'path' on line xx
```

from the answer their I know that function is disabled from the hosting provider.
so I contacted them and they confirmed that, but they didn't provide any  solutions :(

**My question

Is there any work around or alternative solution than using `Mail()`

functionality that may work on the same host?**

Note: I have tried PhpMailer but with no luck.

Comment: Ask your hosting company what mechanism they support?

Comment: @AlexK. they were not helpful at all, but I cant leave them now.

Comment: I have published a low-level SMTP php script that should work on any server unless the function fsockopen() is also disabled. I use this script everyday as part of a cronjob that backups our server. You should not use the scrip if php mail() works, but in your case it does not.  http://www.stringcat.com/company_blog/2012/10/13/complete-php-low-level-mailer-script-with-to-replyto-cc-bcc-and-attachments/